# Is there a EASY way to use a variable in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql, variables, pgadmin

### Using: PostgreSQL10 & pgAdmin4

So this query is simple:

```
SELECT * FROM [schema_name].[table_name] 
   WHERE [schema_name].[table_name].[field_name] = 'search_value';
```

In Transact-SQL you can create a variable for "search_value":

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30) = 'search_value';

SELECT * FROM [schema_name].[table_name] 
   WHERE [schema_name].[table_name].[field_name] = @find;
```

And even re-use the variable:

```
SET @find = 'new_search_value';
```

I have now tried everything to mimic this in PostgreSQL, but I can't get it working.

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with a custom [configuration value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET):

```
SELECT set_config('vars.find', 'search_value', false);

SELECT * FROM schema_name.table_name
   WHERE schema_name.table_name.field_name = current_setting('vars.find');
```

The name [needs a namespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) (`vars` in this case), but you can use any random string for this.

That last boolean parameter to `set_config()` determines whether the new value lasts for the rest of your session (`false`) or resets at the end of the current transaction (`true`).

Comment: Finally a clean cut response. Shot, @nick-barnes !!

I have tried using a With clause, changing the query into a function, declare statements, temp tables, etc. and this makes the most sense (and it might be me coming from an MS SQL background)...